# Is there a function so that $f(f(x))=1/x$?

Tags: functional-equations

I tried to look for a function that fulfills this rule; $$f(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}$$

I tried a lot, and I didn't find anything.

Can anyone help me find such a function? Or prove that there isn't? It doesn't have to be a real function.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ supposed to be?  Do you make any assumptions about what kind of function $f$ is (e.g., continuous)?

Comment: @EricWofsey It can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Well then what is $f(f(0))$ supposed to be?

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right, we have to say $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @76david76 What if $f(0)=c$ were defined, but $f(c)$ were undefined?

Comment: I have a feeling it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Anixx Why is that? (I didn't found)

Comment: Old users can get that feeling.  We tend to have good experience.

Comment: @Annix `I have a feeling it is a duplicate` It is indeed. Top two hits in [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) are [Is there a function whose inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585394/is-there-a-function-whose-inverse-is-exactly-the-reciprocal-of-the-function-tha) and [Is there a continuous function f(x) such that the inverse function is 1/f(x)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387367/is-there-a-continuous-function-fx-such-that-the-inverse-function-is-1-fx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define $f$ on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ as:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x&x>0\\
-\frac1x&x<0\\
\end{cases}$$

There are infinitely many similar functions - if $g:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ is any $1-1$ and onto function with $g(1/x)=1/g(x)$ then:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-g(x)&x>0\\
\frac{1}{g^{-1}(-x)}&x<0
\end{cases}$$

has this property.

Comment: Whoops, yes. @EricWofsey

Comment: I would add that you can find many such $g$ by taking $g:(1,\infty)\to(1,\infty)$ to be any bijection and then extending $g$ to $(0,1)$ so that $g(1/x)=1/g(x)$ (and defining $g(1)=1$).  You can even easily find many such $g$ that are continuous by requiring your bijection $(1,\infty)\to(1,\infty)$ to be order-preserving.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey and finding such g would amount to answering the original question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, @Anixx. It's certainly not an "equally hard" problem - there are lots of simple examples of such a $g$, include $g(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1/x$. But

Answer (score 7):

There is no such function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ that is continuous.  Indeed, note that $x\mapsto 1/x$ induces multiplication by $-1$ on $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, which cannot be $f_*\circ f_*$ for any homomorphism $f_*:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Similarly, there is no such continuous function $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$, since $f$ would have to be injective and thus monotone, and then $f\circ f$ would be increasing no matter what.

You can get such a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ by defining
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x&\text{ if }x>0\\
-1/x&\text{ if } x<0.\end{cases}$$

Finally, if you don't require continuity, it is very easy to get such functions.  Here's one way to do so.  Just define $f(1)=1$, $f(-1)=-1$, and then partition the rest of the domain of $f$ into sets of the form $\{a,1/a,b,1/b\}$ (where these elements are all distinct).  In each such set, define $f(a)=b$, $f(b)=1/a$, $f(1/a)=1/b$, and $f(1/b)=a$.

Comment: I do not see where in the question it is asked about everywhere continuous function.

Comment: @Anixx The OP was not very restrictive about answers, so it is safe to make assumptions.

Comment: It is totally excessive assumption. For instance, function $f(x)=i+\frac{2}{i + x}$ satisfies the conditions and it is discontinuous at only one point (the pole).

Comment: The question was rather vague about what it is requiring, so I answered it in many different possible interpretations, including both a requirement of continuity and no such requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is infinitely many such functions.

One such function that satisfies the conditions is

$$f(x)=i+\frac{2}{i + x}$$

Comment: @RossMillikan I just evaluated $f(f(x))$ by hand, and I got $1/x$.  Anyways, you input wrong.  It should be $$f(f(x))=i+\frac2{i+(i+\frac2{i+x})}$$

Comment: @Ross Millikan you can see the graphic yourself:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bi+%2B+i%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bi+%2B+x%7D%7D

Comment: You are correct.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we have

$$f(x)=x^n$$

Plugging this in gives

$$(x^n)^n=x^{n^2}=x^{-1}$$

Thus, we have

$$n^2=-1\implies n=\pm i$$

Since these are complex exponents, we must be more careful.  If we restrict $x$ to be positive, we have

$$x^i=e^{i\ln(x)}$$

where we use real valued logarithms.  Thus,

$$f(x)=e^{i\ln(x)},e^{-i\ln(x)}$$

Comment: :/ what is wrong with this answer?  OP says complex functions are allowed.

Comment: Complex exponentiation is not uniquely defined, and you must be careful with your choices of branch if you want to be sure $(x^i)^i=x^{-1}$ is always true.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for reminding me.  :)